# Defining key-value pairs from schema to json

Tags: json, jsonschema, keyvaluepair, json-schema-validator

I am trying to define an object with key value pairs from a JSON schema and validating it at: [Json Schema Validator](http://json-schema-validator.herokuapp.com/) but I am having no joy as there does not seem to be instructions to do so in all the JSON schema sites I have looked up.

My object schema definition is as follows:

```
                "gum guards" : {
                    "type": "object",

                        "properties": {
                        "Color":      { "type": "string" },
                        "product code": { "type": "string" },
                        "color code": { "type": "string"}
                     },
                    "enum" : ["Color", "product code", "color code"]
                }
```

The resulting JSON file should give me values such as:

```
"gum guards" : [
    { "Color" : "Black", "product code" : "gg-7890", "color code" : "#000000" },
    { "Color" : "White", "product code" : "gg-7891", "color code" : "#ffffff" }
]
```

However, the validator is giving me the following error message:

```
[ {
  "level" : "error",
  "schema" : {
   "loadingURI" : "#",
   "pointer" : ""
 },
  "instance" : {
   "pointer" : ""
  },
  "domain" : "validation",
  "keyword" : "type",
  "message" : "instance type (object) does not match any allowed primitive type (allowed:          [\"array\"])",
   "found" : "object",
    "expected" : [ "array" ]
    } ]
```

How do you define an array with key-value/pairs in JSON schema?

SCHEMA:

```
 {
"$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
"title": "List of products",
"type": "array",

    "items": {
        "title": "Product",
        "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "id": {
                    "description": "The unique identifier for a product",
                    "type": "number"
                },
                "Category" : {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "Product Name" : {
                    "type" : "string"
                },

                "gum guards" : {
                    "type": "array",

                        "items": {
                           "Color": { "type": "string" },
                           "product code": { "type": "string" },
                           "color code": { "type": "string"}
                         },
                    "required" : ["Color", "product code", "color code"]
                },
                "Summary" : {
                "type": "object",
                    "properties": {
                        "Description": {
                            "oneOf": [
                                {"$ref" : "json/product_summary.json#1110/description"},
                                {"$ref" : "json/product_summary.json#1111/description"},
                                {"$ref" : "json/product_summary.json#1112/description"},
                                {"$ref" : "json/product_summary.json#1114/description"},
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }


            }






    }
```

OUTPUT:

```
 {
"id" : 1110,
"Device Type" : "handset",
"Product Name" : "Pack of accessories",
"variants" : [
    { "Color" : "Black", "product code" : "gg-09090", "color code" : "#000000" },
    { "Color" : "White", "product code" : "gg-09091", "color code" : "#ffffff" }
],
"Summary" : {

    "description" : "Pack of fighter products with chosen colour guard"
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

The issue is here:

```
            "gum guards" : {
                "type": "object",
```

You've declared that `"gum guards"` must be an object, like:

```
     "gum guards": {"Color" : ...},
```

If you want "gum guards" to be an array, then use `"type": "array"`, and specify the schema for the items using `"items"`:

```
"gum guards": {
    "type": "array",
    "items": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {...},
        "required": ["Color", "product code", "color code"]
    }
}
```

(I've also corrected `"enum"` to `"required"`, because that looked like a mistake.)

Comment: Thanks cloudfeet but I am still getting an warning

Comment: `[ {
  "level" : "warning",
  "schema" : {
    "loadingURI" : "#",
    "pointer" : "/items/properties/gum guards/items"
  },
  "domain" : "syntax",
  "message" : "the following keywords are unknown and will be ignored: [Color, color code, product code]",
  "ignored" : [ "Color", "product code", "s-code" ]
} ]`

Comment: When I validate both JSON output and schema together I also get the following error:

Comment: `"level" : "error",
  "schema" : {
    "loadingURI" : "#",
    "pointer" : ""
  },
  "instance" : {
    "pointer" : ""
  },
  "domain" : "validation",
  "keyword" : "type",
  "message" : "instance type (object) does not match any allowed primitive type (allowed: [\"array\"])",
  "found" : "object",
  "expected" : [ "array" ]
} ]`

Comment: This is caused perhaps by the fact that I need the values of "Color, product code, color code" to be key and their result as "values" as in my example above and the result as a key value triplet, is this possible?

Comment: The first warning seems like you've missed a bracket or something somewhere around your `"properties"` definition.  Your indenting's a bit odd, so that's suspicious.  Would you be able to post the whole schema as a Gist or something?

Comment: Hi cloudfeed. See my edits above. In terms of indentation, it is mostly because of the way stackoverflow formats code so I added extra. I hope that you have enough details above. Thanks